# Java equivalent of Gaussian random function between two numbers?

Tags: java, random, gaussian, normal-distribution

first of all, i'd like you to know that i really lack knowledge/suck at math.
Right now, there is a code algorithm that states the use of a Gaussian random function. I honestly don't know a thing about gaussian random function. All i know in java is math.random().

The equation i would like into the code is in the form:

```
  rand = n(m,v);
```

where n(m,v) represents the gaussian random function with mean (m) and variance (v).
What is the equivalent for this in java?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Random` class supplies the `nextGaussian` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29), a random Gaussian with a mean of `0` and a standard deviation of `1`.

> Returns the next pseudorandom, Gaussian ("normally") distributed double value with mean 0.0 and standard deviation 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.

Try

```
rand = rnd.nextGaussian() * Math.sqrt(v) + m;
```

The `Math.sqrt` is in there to convert a variance to standard deviation.